# Can I have a concise code snippet that would incur JIT inlining please?

Tags: c#, .net, jit, inlining

I'm trying to produce some "Hello World" size C# code snippet that would incur JIT inlining. So far I have this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine( GetAssembly().FullName );
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static Assembly GetAssembly()
    {
        return System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
    }
}
```

which I compile as "Release"-"Any CPU" and "Run without debugging" from Visual Studio. It displays the name of my sample program assembly so clearly `GetAssembly()` is not inlined into `Main()`, otherwise it would display `mscorlib` assembly name.

How do I compose some C# code snippet that would incur JIT inlining?

Comment: I you expect inlining to change the observable behavior of your program, I think you're bound to be disappointed :)

Comment: @jalf: Even when using reflection?

Comment: @jalf: That's not quite correct. Stack traces for example are indeed affected by inlining.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: stack traces do not count as "observable behavior" :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, here's an example:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        CallThrow();
    }

    static void CallThrow()
    {
        Throw();
    }

    static void Throw()
    {
        // Add a condition to try to disuade the JIT
        // compiler from inlining *this* method. Could
        // do this with attributes...
        if (DateTime.Today.Year > 1000)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```

Compile in a release-like mode:

```
csc /o+ /debug- Test.cs
```

Run:

```
c:\Users\Jon\Test>test

Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was
thrown.
   at Test.Throw()
   at Test.Main()
```

Note the stack trace - it looks as if `Throw` was called directly by `Main`, because the code for `CallThrow` was inlined.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of inlining seems incorrect: If `GetAssembly` was inlined, it would still show the name of your program.

Inlining means: "Use the body of the function at the place of the function call". Inlining `GetAssembly` would lead to code equivalent to this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()
                                                    .FullName);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think his point was that `GetAssembly` would be invoked by `Main`, but `Main` is invoked by something in `mscorlib`.

Comment: @Rawling: That's not what he is saying in his question: "clearly `GetAssembly()` is not inlined into `Main()`"

Comment: `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()` returns something different if called directly in `main` as it does if called in a function that is called by `main`. Your code produces a different result than the original code. Thus if inlining occurred turning his code into your code, the output _would_ be different.

Comment: @Rawling: That's not correct. You are free to test it yourself.

Comment: If I combine your code and the question code - e.g. one `WriteLine` with `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()`, one with `GetAssembly()` - I get two different outputs.

Comment: @Rawling: [I don't](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tEM6H.png). I get the same output in Release and Debug and if I start it from within VS or directly from disk.

Comment: ... Oh, that's bizarre. I get `Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities ...` for the call in `Main` and `MyProject ...` for the call in `GetAssembly`. (Edit: When running from VS. When running standalone, I get `MyProject ...` for both, so I owe you an apology for that.)

Comment: I assume you start it with debugging (F5)? Try starting without debugging (Ctrl + F5)

Comment: Aaaand I've just noticed the comment in the question about going "Run without debugging", which also gives me two identical line. I'm just going to go away now.