# Why is my method calling Assembly.GetCallingAssembly() not JIT-inlined?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, inline, jit, vshost.exe

I'm trying to craft a short C# snippet that would illustrate change of `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()` behavior because of JIT-inlining [outlined in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly.aspx). Here's my code so far:

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       Console.WriteLine( GetAssembly().FullName );
       Console.ReadLine();
   }

   static Assembly GetAssembly()
   {
       return System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
   }
}
```

which I build in "Release" and start using "Start Without Debugging" - this setup made code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12686974/57428) incur inlining. The result I see is

```
ConsoleApplication2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

so clearly `GetAssembly()` is not inlined into `Main()`, otherwise I'd see `mscorlib` as the calling assembly.

I've reviewed all the inlining criteria and I don't see why `GetAssembly()` would not be inlined.

Is it somehow possible to know why exactly JIT compiler decided to not inline a call?

Comment: Actually, if you call `Console.WriteLine(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());` in `Main` you get the same result

Comment: @mlorbetske: Nope, I see `mscorlib` being reported.

Comment: I just ran it and got the result of `ConsoleApplication5, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null` from both `Main` and `GetAssembly` what version of .NET are you running?

Comment: @sharptooth I had a long argument in the question you linked and ended up being wrong. Calling `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()` in `main` _when running without debugging_ gives _your_ assembly, not some other "calling" assembly.

Comment: @mlorbetske: Indeed, this turns out to be specific to .NET3.5 with Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: My guess, by way of an answer to your question, is that the JIT didn't seem to think it would help. In .Net 4.5 you can use `[MethodImp(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]` to give a strong suggestion to inline the method's contents, but you're still at the mercy of the JIT.

Comment: Even with .NET3.5 with Visual Studio 2008, I still get `ConsoleApplication1...`

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: @mlorbetske: Windows XP Professional SP3.

Comment: I see no mention of x86 and x64, these 2 JIT's differ wildly. 32-bit JIT is much more agressive when inlining VS the 64-bit one.

Comment: @leppie: That's `Any CPU` being run on 32-bit machine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the declaration for Assembly.GetCallingAssembly() in .NET 3.5:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
public static Assembly GetCallingAssembly()
{
    StackCrawlMark lookForMyCallersCaller = StackCrawlMark.LookForMyCallersCaller;
    return nGetExecutingAssembly(ref lookForMyCallersCaller);
}
```

The StackCrawlMark enum is interesting, "look for my callers caller" can't work well when the caller is going to be inlined.  There's a comment in SSCLI20 source code for thread.cs where the enum gets declared:

> declaring a local var of this enum type and passing it by ref into a function that needs to do a stack crawl will both prevent inlining of the calle [sic] and pass an ESP point to stack crawl to

Which is a good match for what happens in GetCallingAssembly(), it's a local variable and does indeed gets passed by ref.  Not sure what the mechanism is, the jitter can however produce a method attribute named CORINFO_FLG_BAD_INLINEE.  Which in turn forces a call to MethodDesc::SetNotInline().  That's a guess, this is very obscure.

Answer (score 3):

To add my two cents to this. Don't rely on something the JIT *may* do to have your program function correctly.

Some of the conditions that would prohibit the JIT from *being able to* inline a method are as follows (taken from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/29/64717.aspx))

- Methods that are greater than 32 bytes of IL will not be inlined.
- Virtual functions are not inlined.
- Methods that have complex flow control will not be in-lined. Complex flow control is any flow control other than if/then/else; in this case, switch or while.
- Methods that contain exception-handling blocks are not inlined, though methods that throw exceptions are still candidates for inlining.
- If any of the method's formal arguments are structs, the method will not be inlined.

Just because the JIT *could* inline the method, doesn't mean it necessarily will. Combine that with the difference in behavior between build configuration/runtime/OS combinations and, well... there you have it.

More information on the .Net 3.5 SP1 JIT's inlining behavior [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2008/08/19/to-inline-or-not-to-inline-that-is-the-question.aspx)

Comment: Would the conditions that you mention still be valid even if I use [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] annotation above the method name?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your call to `Program.GetAssembly` *was* inlined into `Program.Main`. But you can't see the difference since both `Program.GetAssembly` and `Program.Main` are defined in the same assembly named `ConsoleApplication2`.

Although you can illustrate JIT-inlining in another way:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace A3
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StackFrame[] stackFrames = GetStackFrames();
            foreach (StackFrame stackFrame in stackFrames)
                Console.WriteLine(stackFrame.GetMethod().Name); // write method name

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        //[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        static StackFrame[] GetStackFrames()
        {
            StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace(); // get call stack
            return stackTrace.GetFrames(); // get method calls (frames)
        }
    }
}
```

Without JIT-inlining (e.g. in Debug mode or if `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` attribute is applied to the `GetStackFrames`) it will write at least two lines to console:

1. `GetStackFrames`
2. `Main`

But if inlining occurs, `stackFrames` will contain only one method: `Main`

**Update**

Also, as you can read here: [Debugging and the Hosting Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242202.aspx) and as Rawling mentioned in his comment:

> Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().FullName returns different results
>   depending on whether the hosting process is enabled. If you call
>   Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().FullName with the hosting process
>   enabled, it returns mscorlib. If you call
>   Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().FullName with the hosting process
>   disabled, it returns the application name.

Comment: Well, I was able to do that with just two assemblies, one of them being the one containing `Main()`. Still I don't understand why that call is not inlined.

Comment: @nikolay when OP calls the method that could be inlined directly in Main he gets a different result, leading one to believe it hasn't been inlined

Comment: @mlorbetske Yeah. That's why I suggested another way to illustrate JIT-inlining. PS: I've updated my answer once again.