# How to use wpflocalizeextension in Code-Behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, localization

How can I use [wpflocalizeextension](https://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/documentation) in C# code?
In xaml, for getting a localized string I can use it as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="SomeClass"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:lex="http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com"    
    lex:LocalizeDictionary.DesignCulture="uk-UA"    
   lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultAssembly="DesktopApp"    
   lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultDictionary="Resources">
   <Button Content="{lex:Loc SignInBtn}"/>
```

How can I get a localized string in code, for example `MessageBox.Show("SignInBtn");`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a moment and read [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) to get informed whether you should use tags in titles or not. I'd recommend to read [all of these topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is pretty simple.
The localization keys are stored as *AssemblyName*:**Resources**:*KeyName*, where **Resources** is the `Resources` class name, typically you won't change it to something other.

You can create a simple wrapper to get localized values:

```
using WPFLocalizeExtension.Extensions;

public static class LocalizationProvider
{
    public static T GetLocalizedValue<T>(string key)
    {
        return LocExtension.GetLocalizedValue<T>(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name + ":Resources:" + key);
    }
}
```

So assuming you have created your string resource with the `"SignInBtn"` key, you can just call:

```
MessageBox.Show(LocalizationProvider.GetLocalizedValue<string>("SignInBtn"));
```

Comment: But you loose support for strong typed `MyProject.Properties.Resources.SignInBtn` access.

Comment: You should change the `Resources` to the file name of the resource file you use. For example `Strings` which is used in the examples.

Comment: `GetCallingAssembly` can produce for you unwelcome results if u don't take care https://stackoverflow.com/a/12912473/7429464

Answer (score 4):

I regularly use the following native command and have not encountered any errors yet:

```
LocalizeDictionary.Instance.GetLocalizedObject("keyComesHere", null, LocalizeDictionary.Instance.Culture).ToString()
```

Of course, before casting to string, you should check for null values.

Comment: Passing `null` results in a `NullReferenceException`

Answer (score 2):

mcy's answer worked somehow at first, but later I was getting nulls.

I would prefer to use the 3rd overload to make sure I get the right resource:

```
LocalizeDictionary.Instance.GetLocalizedObject("AssemblyName", "DictionaryName", "Key", LocalizeDictionary.Instance.Culture);
```

Answer (score -1):

use it simply

> Properties.Resources.yourKey